# socket.emit() fires twice - socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm making a one-to-one chatroom.

**Here is my basic algorithm:**

1. accept user's input (nickname) by a form
2. fetch all the existing connections and rooms from server
3. check if this nickname already exists:
   if exists, form submission `return false` ; if not exists, ......

Now I'm having a `socket.emit()` twice bug on **step 2**.

**Here is my client side code:**

```
$('#login').submit(function(e){
   socket.emit('getRoomInfo');
   socket.on('receiveRoomInfo',function(info){

      //Here has some code to fetch person_room list from server. 
      //e.g, person_room[nickname]= roomNO

      if(person_room[nickname]){
           alert('User already exists!');
      }else{
         //show chat
         //hide the form
         //update person_room list
         //do something
      }

   });
   return false;
});
```

**Here is my server side code:**

```
socket.on('getRoomInfo',function(){
    socket.emit('receiveRoomInfo', {'person_room': person_room, 'roomNO': roomNO});
});
```

**Bug Description:**

1. Suppose I open up one form (index.html), and input 'John Snow', submit the form. Everything works fine, form gets hidden, chat shows up. Waiting for
   the other connection...
2. Then I open up another form (index.html), and input 'John Snow', submit the form. Window alerts 'User already exists!'. Form isn't submitted.
3. I erase 'John Snow' and input 'Arya Stark', submit the form. Window still alerts
   'User already exists!', but this time, form gets hidden, chat shows
   up.

**What I've test:**

- Login form is only submitted once
- On client side, `socket.emit('getRoomInfo')` is triggered twice under Bug Description 3, which means `socket.on('receiveRoomInfo')` is triggered twice as well. **So what happens is, 'Arya Stark' gets pushed into the list by the first time, and in the second time, it turns out she already exists in the list, Hence window still alerts 'User already exists!'.**

I've researched a lot of similar questions, but none of them is the same case as this one.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fix the code, but I'm not able to tell the reason behind this bug.

I discovered that under once form submission, `socket.on('receiveRoomInfo')` is triggered twice.

So I set a variable `var userExists=false` under `form.submit()`,

after detected `if(person_room[nickname])`, set `userExists=true`.

Under `socket.on('receiveRoomInfo')`, surround all the code implementation with `if(!userExists)`, so that we can make sure `socket.on('receiveRoomInfo')` is only executed once under once form submission.

I will be waiting for few days for a better idea before I vote my own answer.